# Need advice on VOIP call trunking and termination

Tags: voip, phone-call, truncation

I am working on a project where we make a VOIP phone call to the end user, essentially, exactly like skype does.

The problem is, that all calls from  VOIP need to be terminated as PSTN if it has to call a normal Landline phone. In the indian environment, the govt of India does not permit the call (from mobile to landline/landline to landline etc) if it is through a VOIP service, the call has to end in PSTN at the user end and national laws do not allow this, it only allows call from outside the country to end as PSTN but not from within the country.

Is there a work around solution for this? It is a bit hard to phrase this question but if you have any queries please do ask.

Thank you all so much for your help

Mohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to route the call to a PSTN outside India and then dial the Indian phone number from there.